# Adding ngx-doc-viewer in angular 14

Tags: angularjs

I have installed ngx-doc-viwer using npm install ngx-doc-viewer --save  then imported NgxDocViewerModule and added this:
    `<ngx-doc-viewer url="https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx" viewer="google" style="width:100%;height:93vh;" ></ngx-doc-viewer>`
as shown in the steps under Usage -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer/v/15.0.0

But I'm getting this error:
" Error: node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/lib/document-viewer.component.d.ts:33:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

33     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgxDocViewerComponent, "ngx-doc-viewer", never, { "url": "url"; "queryParams": "queryParams"; "viewerUrl": "viewerUrl"; "googleCheckInterval": "googleCheckInterval"; "googleMaxChecks": "googleMaxChecks"; "disableContent": "disableContent"; "googleCheckContentLoaded": "googleCheckContentLoaded"; "viewer": "viewer"; "overrideLocalhost": "overrideLocalhost"; }, { "loaded": "loaded"; }, never, never, false, never>; "

My Angular version: 14, Node.Js version: v18.12.1 and ngx-doc-viewer version: 15.0.0
`your text`

Answer (score 0):

delete the package and reinstall it with angular version like this :
npm i ngx-doc-viewer@14.0.0